# Completion Handler Call N times

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, rx-swift, completionhandler

In the Button action, I call `getLatLongValues` method, It will return completion property after API success.

Hear problem is, If I click **N** th times in button action, `getLatLongValues` method execute **N** times.
Like I click the button in 1st time `getLatLongValues` execute 1 time, I'm click 2nd time not two times `getLatLongValues` method execute 2 times.

```
@IBAction func updateDeliveryAddress() {
    guard let address = self.addressTextField.text else { return }
    self.getLatLongValues(address, true, viewModel) { success in
        if success {
            //Success
        } else {
            // Error
        }
    }
}

func getLatLongValues(address: String, setAsDefault: Bool, viewModel:ViewModel, completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
    viewModel.location.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] results in
        guard self != nil else { return }
        if let result = results {
                completion(true) // Success
        }
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    viewModel.fetchLocation(address: address)
}
```

Why `getLatLongValues` Execute **N** times?

Comment: You call the function each time the button is pressed. So, everything in the function, including the completion handler, is processed.

Comment: what are you using coreLocations?

Comment: @TusharSharma No, Google geocoding API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because each time you are creating a new subscription.
a subscription is not a completion handler that gets executed once.

```
viewModel.location.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] results in
```

should only be called once, and on each location update, you get the result in the block

Answer (score 2):

If you want the completion handler to only be called once, you should set a flag:

```
var completionHandlerExecuted = false /// false at first

func getLatLongValues(address: String, setAsDefault: Bool, viewModel:ViewModel, completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
    
    if completionHandlerExecuted == false {
        completionHandlerExecuted = true /// set to true, so it won't be called again


        viewModel.location.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] results in
            guard self != nil else { return }
            if let result = results {
                completion(true) // Success
            }
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        viewModel.fetchLocation(address: address)
    }

}
```

Completion handlers are like any other instruction you put in your functions.

Every time `getLatLongValues` is called, you are doing a `subscribe`, which will call the completion handler once it's finished.